# TPU Plastic leaving residue in my bed

Tags: heated-bed, cleaning, plastic

How do I remove the residue left by TPU plastic ? I used to print with ABS plastic and while it left a little bit of residue, I could remove it with Isopropyl alcohol and then scrap it with my spatula.

However, I just did my first print with TPU and it left a ring in my bed. No matter how hard I scrap or rub with the alcohol it won't go off :(

Any tips ?
Edit here are my images:

[image: Plastic]

[image: Bed]

Comment: As an aside, is it real TPU? I found the flex-PLA material I first tried printing flexible with was a mess to clean up, but real TPU was no problem.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE how do I know if it's real TPU :S ? I bought Anycubic filament, so I was hoping it was the real thing :(

Comment: Can't you rub it off with your fingers? (Like stickers residue)

Comment: If it's sold as TPU and from a reputable brand, especially if it advertises properties of TPU like chemical and abrasion resistance, then it probably is. But some filaments are sold as just "flexible filament" or have the word TPU somewhere in the writeup so they turn up in TPU search results, but aren't actually claiming to be TPU. Some of them even claim being "easier to print" thant TPU, which from my experience is a load of bs - real TPU is so much easier to print.

Comment: @0scar no sadly. I tried rubbing it with the spatula too, and it wouldn't go off.

Comment: Is this an Ultrabase bed surface?

Comment: it's the stock bed that came with my 3d printer (anycubic mega s)